# How to programmatically check which version of unicode is supported by GLib

Tags: unicode, glib

I've seen that the support of the 3-em dash inside GLib must be rather recent, since it was only introduced in Unicode 6.1.0. A more general question originating from this: Is it possible to programmatically determine the supported unicode version, without sifting through GLib changelogs? (EDIT: https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.31/glib-2.31.20.changes gave me the information that support for version 6.1.0 was added with 2.31.20, for example.)

The GLib reference manual states

> The implementations of the Unicode functions in GLib are based on the
>   Unicode Character Data tables, which are available from
>   www.unicode.org. GLib 2.8 supports Unicode 4.0, GLib 2.10 supports
>   Unicode 4.1, GLib 2.12 supports Unicode 5.0, GLib 2.16.3 supports
>   Unicode 5.1, GLib 2.30 supports Unicode 6.0.

which is a bit vague for a case affected by recent subversions. (AFAIK the current supported version is at least 8.0 now anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to programmatically determine the supported unicode version, without sifting through GLib changelogs?

tl;dr: No. As with the rest of the version checking in GLib, it’s all based on calling [`glib_check_version()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Version-Information.html#glib-check-version) (or the [`GLIB_CHECK_VERSION()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Version-Information.html#GLIB-CHECK-VERSION:CAPS) macro if you want to check at build time) and comparing that against a version which you know contains what you want. It’s the same for whether you want to check if a certain function is available or whether a given version of Unicode is supported.

Currently, the only way to know which version of GLib supports a given version of Unicode is to look at the changelogs, as you’ve found.

I’ve submitted a [merge request](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/merge_requests/1426) to update the documentation to list the version history for supporting Unicode though.

As a data point, GLib 2.64 (the latest stable version) supports Unicode 12.1.

Comment: See the merge request link in my updated answer. Thanks for pointing out the need for it :)